# Что лучше 1 БД и 1000-2000 таблиц или 100 БД по 20 таблиц

Tags: wordpress, mysql

Есть VDS, на котором много WP сайтов.

Что лучше по производительности, все сайты на WP ставить в 1 БД с разными префиксами, или для каждого сайта заводить отдельную БД?

Вопрос безопасности понятен, и в данном случае не рассматривается.

Comment: Не сложно будет администрировать, поддерживать и т.д. 100 БД? И еще, нужно добавить некое поле в некую таблицу которое должно поддерживать много WP сайтов, по вашему проще это сделать для одной БД или когда их туча?

Comment: По мне, так одна программа - одна БД, пусть хоть там миллион таблиц.

Comment: Сейчас у нас 100 БД, и за год я их даже не смотрел, нету необходимости. Единственное что делал так базу откатывал назад из бекапа для 1 сайта.

Comment: По производительности не знаю, а по безопастности лучше 100бд с разными пользователями. Т.к. если взломают 1 из 100 блогов, считай что и остальные взломали)

Comment: Лучше одна хорошо спроектированная БД, но, если есть необходимость можно разбить приложение на модули и использовать для каждого модуля свою БД. Лично мы использовали второй подход на Zend Framework.

Comment: Люди, всё понятно и так, вопрос стоит не абстрактный а конкретный, именно 1 БД и куча таблиц или куча БД. Приложение WordPress. Всё. Про безопасность я прекрасно знаю, и в вопросе это написал.

В конечном итоге придётся использовать как есть куча БД по 20 таблиц, т.к. пару плагинов не используют префикс к своим таблицам :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Производительность будет абсолютно одинаковая и в том и в другом случае. Здесь надо исходить от личной производительности ежели машинной.

Comment: тут я с вами не соглашусь! корявый запрос, база задумалась, и все что в ней тоже задумалось..
а если 100 бд, то такого не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Определенно, дабы не было конфликтов данных и путаницы, я бы сделал для каждого отдельного сайта - отдельную БД.

Comment: Конфликтов данных и не будет у WP везде используются префиксы к таблицам, у всех нормальных плагинов тоже...Вот путаница..хм.

Comment: Тут, если особой разницы в реализации по производительности нет, я смотрю, прежде всего, на удобство представления и поддержки.

Answer (score 1):

Практика хранения таблиц для разных программ в одной базе, пусть с префиксами разными или еще как, сложилась из-за нищебродских тарифных планов всяких хостеров, которые не хотят давать несколько баз одновременно, но ни разу не как средство оптимизации производительности или еще чего.

Comment: согласен !